# Activiti Engine: Task Event - User is null

Tags: java, activiti

I have a problem with the activiti engine, which should be simple to solve, but i can't find the method to call to solve this problem:

My problem is, that every Task Event (org.activiti.engine.task.Event) returnes null by calling Event.getUserId();
If I take a look into the database I see that the database table ACT_HI_COMMENT has null as value for the column USER_ID_ for every row.

I generate these TaskEvents programmatically by calling (for example)

```
processEngine.getTaskService().addComment(task.getId(),    null, commentMessage);

processEngine.getTaskService().addUserIdentityLink(task.getId(), user.getId(), IDENTITY_LINK_OBSERVER);
```

I guess there is a simple method that I must call to solve this problem, something like processEngine.setCurrentUser(authenticatedUser.getId());

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `authenticatedUserId` in the `IdentityService` should do the trick:

```
processEngine.getIdentityService().setAuthenticatedUserId(user.getId());
```

Comment: It appears as though this has changed. Do you know the current API, if one exists, to automatically assign tasks to an initiating user?